# PHP \ MySql query error

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

i'm having a problem with a php page on my webserver:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/vyhtpnwt/public_html/include/main.php on line 12

Line 12 on the page is:

```
foreach ($conn->query("SELECT * FROM accountType WHERE id=".$accountTypeID) as $row2) {
$accountType = $row2[$lang['dbLabel']];
if ($row2['expirationDays']==999) {$accountExp = $lang['unlimitedExp'];} else {
//expiration date script!
$accountExp = 0;
}
```

Considering that:

- $conn works properly on other scripts;
- $accountTypeID is populated and it's = 1;
- he SELECT return 1 result;
- fields expirationDays
- $lang['dbLabel'] and $lang['unlimitedExp'] are correctly populated.

what can be the problem?

Thanks in advance for your precious help!!!

Comment: The error is "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" so it should be completely logical that whatever $conn->query() returns is not something you can iterate over. Do a var_dump($conn->query( .. ))

Comment: Did you forget to require the file containing $conn?

Comment: When composing queries, use [placeholder values to properly escape data](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You shouldn't be using string concatenation to compose queries with data that may not be properly escaped. The risk of a mistake is way too high. What database interface are you using? PDO? I don't think you're using it correctly here.

Comment: little Johnny Tables strikes again

Comment: Missing `}` for `foreach ($conn->query("SELECT * FROM accountType WHERE id=".$accountTypeID) as $row2) {
$accountType = $row2[$lang['dbLabel']];`

Comment: RonniSkansing - the var_dump return bool(false)
JacobGoulden - the file containing $conn is included
tadman - thanks for the advice! i will perform the mods suggested, yes i'm using PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you very much for all your suggestions!
I finally found the error!!! 
I was working on Windows server when i wrote the code and remote server is Linux based, for this reason i didn't see a mistake on the uppercase letter of the table name!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$q = $conn->query
("SELECT * FROM
accountType WHERE id=".
$accountTypeID);
$ar = $q->fetch_assoc():

foreach( $ar as $row2)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Because you haven't actually fetched the array from that code, you simply fetched the mysqli_query object itself, which isn't the array of values you want/need